# Create Table - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

How can I create a table just like another one on SQL Server 2008 by using a Query, As I tried this query but it doesn't work.

**Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable AS MyOldTable
```

**Error:**

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'As'

Answer (score 5):

`CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT * FROM old_table);`

Will work.

Comment: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '('.`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable AS (SELECT * FROM myoldtable);
```

Comment: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '('.`

Answer (score 0):

**Using SQL Server Management Studio**

From source table contextual menu you select `Script Table as` > `CREATE To` > `New Query Editor Window`:
[image]

Then you edit the source code changing, for example, the name of table (the new name):

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [HumanResources].[Employee]    Script Date: 1/4/2014 1:05:14 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [HumanResources].[AuditEmployee]( -- <-- Here you change table name
    [BusinessEntityID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NationalIDNumber] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [LoginID] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    ...
```